# Any way to change the tab size of the diff command's output?

Tags: osx, diff, whitespace

I'm on OSX and running a `diff` command like this, to create side-by-side output:

```
$] diff -Bbwy --width=200 --suppress-common-lines file1.txt file2.txt > diff-output.txt
```

It outputs my diffs just fine, but it uses tabs for indentation of the output (alignment of the side-by-side middle line, etc). Additionally, the files in question also use tabs for indentation inside them, so the diff output has all these tab characters in them.

I want the output of `diff` to have spaces, specifically 4-space's instead of tabs.

I know `diff` supports the `-t` option to do just that, but the problem is it uses a fixed size of 8-spaces for all tabs (not only the leading line indentation tabs from the original files, but also its alignment tabs to keep the middle line aligned, etc).

I've tried a variety of post-processing approaches to take the tabs (or spaces) from `diff` output and shrink them to the desired size of 4-spaces, but that always just causes mis-alignments of the `diff` side-by-side output.

Then I thought maybe I could pre-process the two files being `diff`ed, using `tab2space` or something like that, to get each file's line indentations from tabs to 4-spaces before diffing. But I can't work out how, without temporary files, to then get both of those pre-processed inputs piped into `diff`.

Can that be done?

Or is there any other approach I've not tried? Any secret way to config/force `diff -t` to just use 4-space tabs instead of 8?

Comment: BTW, I believe that `-bw` is redundant. Do you find that it behaves differently from `-b`?

Comment: I don't know that I'm seeing any difference between `-b`, `-w`, and `-bw`, but they seemed like they could be different as they're listed separately. Shrugs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
diff  (options)  <(expand -t4 file1.txt)  <(expand -t4 file2.txt)
```

will expand tabs in the input files to spaces,
assuming tab stops set every four columns. 
Combining this with `diff`’s `-t` option should get you what you want.

Comment: Awesome, that worked perfectly. I was trying `|` and had completely forgotten about `<`. :)

Comment: For the record, process substitution `<(COMMAND)` and `>(COMMAND)` (and in Zsh also `=(COMMAND)`) are different from file redirection `<FILE` and `2>FILE` (etc).